# Preciso que COUNT retorne 0

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas com os seguintes dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero resgatar do banco todos os usuários e a quantidade de trabalhos que eles realizaram. Estava usando o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT u.usuario, COUNT(t.id) AS '4' 
FROM usuario u LEFT JOIN trabalho t 
ON u.usuario = t.idUsuario 
WHERE t.realizado = 1 
AND t.dataTermino <= '2018-05-01' 
AND t.dataTermino >= '2018-04-01' 
GROUP BY u.usuario
```

O problema é que, caso não existam trabalhos realizados para um usuário, a linha não é retornada, e quero que retorne o nome do usuário e `0`.

Comment: A do fechamento é similar, mas creio que seu caso o "WHERE t.realizado = 1" só atrapalha, não?

Comment: Pergunta fechada, mas segue a minha [solução](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30731/1)

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/467840-resolvido%C2%A0select-com-group-by-mesmo-sem-registro-correspondente/?do=findComment&comment=1855090    veja se ajuda